# Javascript Function: Applying Apply

Tags: javascript

I got stumped by this weirdness.

Let's say I have this array:

```
var array = [{
  something: 'special'
}, 'and', 'a', 'bunch', 'of', 'parameters'];
```

Could I `apply` the `apply` method of a function to invoke the function with the `this` object being `{something: 'special'}` and the parameters being the rest of `array`?

In other words, could I do this

```
var tester = function() {
  console.log('this,', this);
  console.log('args,', arguments);
};
tester.apply.apply(tester, array);
```

And expect the output to be the following?

```
> this, {"something": "special"}
> args, {"0": "and", "1": "a", "2": "bunch", "3": "of", "4": "parameters"}
```

I tried it.

```
TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type
```

But why?  It seems like this should work.

Comment: tester.apply(tester, array); is what you want...

Comment: @dandavis Not really. The value of `this` should be `array[0]`, and the arguments passed should be `array[1]` to `array[len-1]`

Comment: @Ian: sorry, misunderstood.  eval.call.apply(tester, array) works, since you want to apply the call (confused yet, heh)..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But why?

Let's reduce your calls step-by-step:

```
tester.apply.apply(tester, array) // resolves to
(Function.prototype.apply).apply(tester, array) // does a
tester.apply({something: 'special'}, 'and', 'a', 'bunch', 'of', 'parameters');
```

Here you can see what's going wrong. Correct would be

```
var array = [
    {something: 'special'},
    ['and', 'a', 'bunch', 'of', 'parameters']
];
```

then the `apply.apply(tester, array)` would become

```
tester.apply({something: 'special'}, ['and', 'a', 'bunch', 'of', 'parameters']);
```

which does a

```
tester.call({something: 'special'}, 'and', 'a', 'bunch', 'of', 'parameters');
```

So with your original `array` you'd need to use

```
(Function.prototype.call).apply(tester, array)
```

Comment: you can be lazy: Function.prototype.call === Function.call === true

Comment: or, indeed, `tester.call`

Comment: i use eval because it's reliable and only 4 letters without a shift (unlike Date and atob)...

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to emphasize that the function is accessed without a specific context - that's why I've also put it in brackets.

Comment: That definitely makes sense. Just didn't think through it enough. I guess...I kinda liked the tongue-twister of `apply`ing `apply.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The apply method takes one argument for the `this` context and one argument for the arguments, that you want to apply. The second argument must be an array.

```
tester.apply.apply(tester, array);
```

Due to the second apply method, the first will be called like this:

```
tester.apply({something: 'special'}, 'and', 'a', 'bunch', 'of', 'parameters');
```

And since 'and' is not an array, you get the TypeError that you described. You can easily fix this by using the `call` method:

```
tester.call.apply(tester, array);
```

`call` will take individual arguments instead of an array, which will result in the desired outcome.